# Mac's Slack window is on every space on High Sierra

Tags: macos, osx-spaces, macos-highsierra, slack, expose

I am using Slack on a Macbook Pro with an external monitor. For some reason, the slack window is on every space on a certain screen. i.e. if I have a slack window open in the center of the screen, then even when I move one space right or left, the slack window will retain its position and will be visible on every space.

I can't share the video because of the sensitive content but If the question isn't clear, then I can try to hack something up to make a screencast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click it in the Dock > Options > check anything except "All Desktops"

[image]

Comment: thanks! that took me way to long to find .